# Sed regex: difference between -E and BRE (Sed & Awk 101 hacks)

Tags: text-processing, sed, regular-expression

Currently I am self learning awk and sed. I found the online book Sed & Awk 101 hacks which I found very good so far. Nevertheless, I came across I haven't continue for a few days because I can't get the concept "grouping"
Here is the input file

```
cat employee.txt
101,John Doe,CEO
102,Jason Smith,IT Manager
103,Raj Reddy,Sysadmin
104,Anand Ram,Developer
105,Jane Miller,Sales Manager
```

The book sed command is the following:

```
sed 's/\([^,]*\).*/\1/g' employee.txt
```

The output of this command is:

```
101
102
103
104
105
```

I have tried to understand that command but it doesn't make sense to me. Then, after checking the sed documentation (man sed) I noticed that when the flag -E is not used then the regular expression takes the BRE syntax. Could you tell me why this expression doesn't work to get the same input?

```
sed -E 's/^(\d+),.+/\1/g' employee.txt
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A handy reference for GNU tools using regular expressions: https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/Regular-expression-syntaxes.html#Regular-expression-syntaxes

Answer (score 2):

The `\d` doesn't work in `sed`. You can use `[[:digit:]]` or `[0-9]` instead:

```
sed -E 's/^([[:digit:]]+),.+/\1/' employee.txt
sed -E 's/^([0-9]+),.+/\1/' employee.txt
```

Note that I removed the `g` at the end which is not needed in your examples.

Related:

- [Why doesn't `\d` work in regular expressions in sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14671293/why-doesnt-d-work-in-regular-expressions-in-sed)
- [How to match digits followed by a dot using sed?](https://superuser.com/questions/513412/how-to-match-digits-followed-by-a-dot-using-sed)